# Query won't match using LIKE with returned ajax data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to match up profiles in my MySQl database with the names and skillsets that are dropped into my droppable div, [See HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/181/). I come across two problems one being the error `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` which I believe means my query is returning false. That takes me to the other problem, my $data not matching anything. How can I match the names and skills dropped into the droppable div with the names and skills in my database?

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gradesheet WHERE 'firstname','lastname','grade' LIKE '{$data}'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $firstname=$row['firstname'];
            $lastname=$row['lastname'];
            $gradet=$row['grade'];
            $user_id=$row['user_id'];

echo $firstname;
```

I used `%Like%` thinking it would give me a better chance than `MATCH AGAINST`. I would appreciate any knowledge or ideas on matching my query better and having it return something. As well as any tips in general.

Comment: Your code is terribly insecure.  You are wide open to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LIKE` for each of the columns in your `WHERE` statement, and choose either `AND` or `OR` to bring them together. The percent symbol `%` is a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM gradesheet 
WHERE 'firstname' LIKE '%term%' 
    OR 'lastname' LIKE '%term%' 
    OR 'grade' LIKE '%term%'
```

You should also avoid using the `mysql_*` PHP extensions as they have been [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799); use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Aside from using deprecated extensions, your code is also wide open for a SQL injection attack. You should always filter data from request variables before sticking it into a query.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!! @doublesharp do know any good tutorials on either PDO or mysqli??

Comment: The "PDO" and "mysqli" text in the answer are both linked to the docs which include examples, but I don't know of any good tutorials off the top of my head - I'm sure Google can help though ;)

Comment: Ok I really appreciate the help!